# Subtract a constant from a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
year,value
1970,2.0729729191557147
1971,1.0184197388632872
1972,2.574009084167593
1973,1.4986879160266255
1974,3.0246498975934464
1975,1.7876222478238608
1976,2.5631745148930913
1977,2.444014336917563
1978,2.619502688172043
1979,2.268273809523809
1980,2.6086169818316645
1981,0.8452720174091145
1982,1.3158922171018947
1983,-0.12695212493599603
1984,1.4374230626622169
1985,2.389290834613415
1986,2.3489311315924217
1987,2.6002265745007676
1988,1.2623717711036955
1989,1.1793426779313878
```

I would like to subtract a constant from each of the values in the second column. This is the code I have tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv(f1, sep=",", header=0)
df2 = df["value"].subtract(1)
```

However when I do this, df2 becomes this:

```
70    1.072973
71    0.018420
72    1.574009
73    0.498688
74    2.024650
75    0.787622
76    1.563175
77    1.444014
78    1.619503
79    1.268274
80    1.608617
81   -0.154728
82    0.315892
83   -1.126952
84    0.437423
85    1.389291
86    1.348931
87    1.600227
88    0.262372
89    0.179343
```

The year becomes only the last two digits. How can I retain all of the digits of the year?

Answer (score 3):

I think column `year` is not modified, only need assign back subtracted values:

```
df["value"] = df["value"].subtract(1)
```